# Force user to enter login even if logged in with Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook

I have an implementation of Faceebook connect and I have noticed that if you are already logged in to facebook and hit connect, you wont be prompted for your login credentials (because it takes current session data).

Is there anyway to make Facebook connect not use the currently logged in user and force each connect to enter their login/pw?

Comment: What CMS (or similar) are you using for your site?

Comment: @anschauung how is that relevant? As far as I know, you can't force them to re-enter their login/password.  This kind of eliminates the convenience of FB connect.

Comment: Is it possible to logout of facebook connect?

Comment: I am using facebooker with ruby on rails 2.2.2. The issue is if the currently logged in user to facebook isnt the desired user to connect with, they then have unlink their facebook account. The only way we can get the popup with the login form is if nobody is logged into facebook on that browser.

Comment: You could log the current user out before they try to log in, but this would annoy tons of users.  If you're really looking to force someone to login every time, look for options other than FB connect.

Comment: They dont need to log in with fbconnect every time, once we have their facebook information they dont need to log in with facebook again. I want to force the login on first connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I believe if you already have the facebook application installed, it bypasses a 2nd window.

Comment: I see that you have accepted your own reply. Did you ever find a solution for that problem? If yes could you share? I'm currently running into the exact same issue. I have to work on this application and the marketing people drank the facebook-connect Kool Aid. I thought it worked like OpenID, but it only checks if you're connected to the facebook network and if you are, then you have the green light. No login popup, nothing. I fail to see how that's cool.

Comment: I haven't exactly found a solution to it. I have found that facebook adds certain classes to the FB button depending on the status of the user but at this time I'm not sure if you can manipulate that manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using re-authentication. Quoting:

> In apps where security is very important, you may want to double-check someone's identity - perhaps before they make a purchase within the app, or use it to access some sensitive personal data.
>
> To prevent situations where a user could leave a device logged in or man-in-the-middle hijacking of the user session, re-authentication forces a person to re-enter their Facebook password before they can continue to use your app.

For more information, see:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-re-auth/

Answer (score 0):

Go to facebook App settings. under Advance tab look for "Force Web OAuth Reauthentication" make that YES. and save it.

From now on your login will ask for user password every time even if facebook browser session is present.